# How to open facebook session using custom button in Android using Facebook 3.0 SDK?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using a custom button Instead of the LoginButton given by facebook to login to my app.

This is my code on button click:

```
 Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new StatusCallback() 
        {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "jbfjdfbgh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

But my session state is "OPENING".

This is the exact Session: **Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add permissions and don't use break points to check the status. This should solve your problem.